# What’s the science behind thenkuzhal (its a crispy snack, crispy hollow tubes)?

Tags: dough, food-science, deep-frying, snacks

How/why does the hollow form inside this crispy snack? It is made from rice flour dough. For more details please check https://kalaskalai.wordpress.com/2015/12/20/thaenkuzhal-murukku/

Answer (score 1):

I think the hollow comes from air expanding while frying the dough.

At first I thought it was made like an Italian bucatini ([with a die](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30W3Hmsg4ro)), but watching videos showing how [Thaenkuzhal is made](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wa3xjdUvhzw), I think it's only air expanding